# How to create a SQL Schema in a Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

How can I create a sql schema in a Query? I'm using MS SQL Server Management Studio (SQL Server 2008).

Comment: looking just for that, or did I miss something : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms189462.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like this.

```
USE [Sandbox]
GO

/****** Object:  Schema [MySchema]    Script Date: 08-05-2013 11:23:16 ******/
CREATE SCHEMA [MySchema]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check out your solution on below link

[Microsoft MSDN link:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189462.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189462.aspx)

http://www.sql.org/sql-database/postgresql/manual/sql-createschema.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate the schema before creating it, there is important information in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18712751/2296441