# Can i create schema in Store Procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can i create `schema` in `Store Procedure` in SQL Server. I tried this

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE makadmin.createCustomerSchema 
 (@tenant nvarchar(30) ,
  @companyId int , 
  @saleId bigint  )
  AS
  Begin
  create schema @tenant authorization  createcustomerschema)
  End
```

Is it possible or I am heading in wrong direction?

Comment: You will  need to use Dynamic SQL to do this. Wonder why you want to create a schema from a storedproc. I do not see any error handling. What happens when the SP is called again with same values for the parameters?

Comment: `CREATE SCHEMA` statement can only be in batch statement, so you cannot put it in Stored procedure, except creating dynamic SQL

Answer (score 5):

To issue `CREATE` statements from inside a stored procedure, use `EXEC sp_executesql`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE createCustomerSchema 
 (@tenant nvarchar(30) ,
  @companyId int , 
  @saleId bigint  )
  AS
  Begin
    declare @sql nvarchar(4000) = 'create schema ' + @tenant + ' authorization  createcustomerschema';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql

  End
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this since 'CREATE SCHEMA' must be the first statement in a query batch.

You can create schema as follows with dynamic sql, and it is better to check whether schema is already exist in the database.

```
DECLARE @cmd varchar(1000)
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = @tenant)
  BEGIN
    SET @cmd='CREATE SCHEMA '+@tenant + ' authorization  createcustomerschema';
    EXEC (@cmd);
  END;
```